# What is it called when you plan to writing one word but end up writing another thats similar in writing but different in meaning

Tags: neuroscience, language, writing, typing

Is there a name for when you're thinking of one word, you're writing/typing it in but end up writing/typing another word with a different meaning yet similar typing happens? I often have this problem and I just wondered what is its name so I could finally put my finger on it and *maybe*, *hopefully* somehow resolve it.

For example, life and like. F and K and fairly far apart on the keyboard, and are written with different hands. same with have-hate and many other words, its always just one letter off and it happens in every language I know, its not isolated to just English. Happens both when writing and when typing. And to be honest, when you're trying to sound professional and end up making these mistake (which most text correction do not catch) its just frustrating.